# SQL query in which count function is in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table where I am tracking association between departments and budget centers. The association is many-to-many. Now I want to display only those departments which have more than 10 budget centers associated to them. SO my query should be something like this

```
select dept,
       count(budget_centers) as bcCount
from myTable
where bcCount > 10
group by dept
```

Now oracle will give an error saying "bcCount" is an invalid identifier. Is there a way to rephrase the query which will be acceptable in oracle

Comment: You might have luck by using [`having`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/having.php) instead of `where`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agreed. I updated it with a different link, though you have already listed better references in your answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what the `having` clause is for:

```
select dept,
       count(budget_centers) as bcCount
from myTable
group by dept
having count(budget_centers) > 10
```

Here are the relevant parts of the manual:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2066419
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55384

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
select dept,
       count(budget_centers) as bcCount
from myTable
group by dept
having count(budget_centers) > 10
```